# Combining 2 result sets in AQL

Tags: arangodb, aql

Is there a way to combine 2 results sets (got via 2 different queries) into a single results set? Something like the following?

```
let results1 = (query1) // ["1","2"]
let results2 = (query2) // ["3","4"]

for r in MERGE_RESULTS(results1,results2) return r // ["1","2","3","4"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LET results1 = ["1","2"]
LET results2 = ["3","4"]
FOR x IN UNION(results1, results2)
RETURN x
```

yields an array with the four elements.

UNION_DISTINCT() does the obvious thing.

You could simply RETURN UNION(_,_), but in that case the result would be an array with one item, namely the array of interest:

```
[
  [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Just for reference, there is also "APPEND": `LET results1 = ["1","2"]
LET results2 = ["3","4"] RETURN APPEND(results1, results2)`.